# Find basis and dimension of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have

$V=\{(x,y,z,w)\in \mathbb{R}^4 : x+y=z+w\}$

How I can find basis and dimension?

I'm new and I don't know how to proceed

Comment: Did you mean $\mathbb R^\color{red}4?$

Comment: Yes, I wrote bad

Comment: As for finding a basis, a common tactic is to suppose one or more of the variables are "*free variables*" and parametrize the set of solutions using those free variables.  The dimension is simply the number of vectors in the basis

Comment: It’s a hyperplane of dimension $3$ with basis e.g. $(1,0,1,0), (1,0,0,1), (0,1,0,1)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

A vector of $ V $ is of the form
$$(x,y,z,w)=(x,y,z,x+y-z)=$$

$$x(1,0,0,1)+y(0,1,0,1)+z(0,0,1,-1)=$$
$$x\vec{v_1}+y\vec{v_2}+z\vec{v_3}$$

Now prove these three vectors are independent.

Answer (score 2):

You can write the condition given as: $x+y-z-w=0$ (a *homogeneous* system). The solution set to this system is given by (note $3$ free variables)
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\w\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-y+z+w\\y\\z\\w\end{bmatrix}=y\begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+w\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$
So a basis is given by the three vectors (linearly independent and spanning the solution set) on the RHS and hence the dimension is $3$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation can be re-arranged to give
$$x + y - z - w = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & -1 & -1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ w \end{bmatrix} = A \vec{x} = 0$$
So the solution set is exactly the set of vectors which constitute the null-space of the matrix $A$. You can use Gaussian elimination to find such a basis.

To find the dimension, you can either count the number of basis elements or you can note here that we have one non-trivial equation, so the dimension of the solution space will be $1$ less than the dimension of $\mathbb{R}^4$. In general, if you know you have $m$ linearly independent equations in a vector space $V$ with dimension $n$, then the dimension of the solution set will be $n - m$.